# Android USB HOST discovering a device

Tags: android, filter, usb, device, host

I'm trying to connect a USB device to Samsumg Galaxy, using an OTG cable. I have made a simple code, based on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html tutorial, but it simply doesn't work. what I have realized so far is that action is always android.intent.action.MAIN. and maybe that's why the device is always null. has someone had any luck with this kind of program?

this is my code:

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_microstrain);

EditText find_device = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.find_device);

Intent intent = getIntent();

String action = intent.getAction();
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), action,  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();

UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

UsbAccessory device = (UsbAccessory)  intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY);

find_device.setText((CharSequence) device);

}
```

and the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.microstrain.MICROSTRAIN"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

       <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter> 
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
    </intent-filter>
         <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"  
             android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
    </activity>
   <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
</application>

<instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
android:targetPackage="com.example.microstrain"
android:label="microstrain" />
```

and xml/device_filter.xmk:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
   <usb-device vendor-id="6555" product-id="15717"/>  
</resources>
```

Comment: you do not understand what are you doing ... if you wana list of attached devices then use `UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
...
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();` if you wana show some Activity when some device is connected then use code from Guide ... now when you starts Activity from Launcher/Home App there is no `UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE` in intent ... it's only appear when Activity is started from  "attach event"(when new device desribed in `device_filter` is attached)

Comment: There also seems to be these known issues with USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED & USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED. [1](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=25703) & [2](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25701)

Comment: @TronicZomB hmmmm about first issue ... how about `android:launchMode="singleInstance` +  override `onNewIntent` ...

Comment: @Selvin I haven't tried that one yet. I did end up trying `android:launchMode="singleTask"` and that seems to be working so far. Thanks.

Comment: I have also tried UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE); HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList(); Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator(); while(deviceIterator.hasNext()){ UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next(); numerous times but without success. Even now I added android:launchMode="singleTask" and still nothing.